# Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression - SQL to pull 1 ID back in resultset

Tags: sql, syntax, operator-keyword

please find below my SQL statement, on line 20 the error is apparently;

https://gist.github.com/815c4dd5655e79581a1a

current error im getting is

```
Microsoft Access Database Engine error '80040e14'

Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'sea_Reference=A01AND sea_TheID=5'.

/STUDENT/s0191958/PART2/bookingprocess1.asp, line 22
```

all the variables being requested and stuff, are digits.

Ive been removing and adding quotes all night and im sick of it!

Answer (score 1):

**Put a space before the AND and put the data for sea_Reference in quotes.**

Change: 'sea_Reference=A01AND sea_TheID=5'

to 'sea_Reference='A01' **AND** sea_TheID=5'

here's the altered code

```
SeatSetRs="SELECT sea_ID FROM seat WHERE sea_Reference='" & request("firstSeat") & "' AND sea_TheID=" & request("the_ID") & ""
```

Comment: I've answered the question you posted. Can you try and run the sql created manually and post another question with problem please?

Comment: You beautiful man. We have a rendered page! I shall battle the errors on the page and let you know how it goes :P

Comment: Ok relating to that, the sea_ID, I want to grab, I want to print out into a textbox below; like so
value="<%=SeatSetRs.sea_ID%>" Is that the correct way?

Comment: @Kieronboz - sorry not done asp for nearly 12 years, but I think that's about right.